# How to get all the documents using the id of a foreign field in the model?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a model Comments that store reference to post model in its schema

```
let commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  post: {
    type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:"post"
    
  },
  user:{
    type:"String"
  },
  commentBy:{
    type:String,
  },
  date: {
    type: String,
  },
  commentMessage: {
    type: String,
  },
  replies:[
      {
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"Reply"
      }
    ]
})
```

Now I get the id of a post from frontend, what can I do to get all the comments which have a post with same post id?

Answer (score 2):

```
await commentSchema.find({post:ObjectId(id)})
```

This will return all comments with matching with id(post id). Note You should convert id to ObjectId, from frontend id will be in string format.

```
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb')
```

use mongodb npm for conversion.

Comment: Thanks Ethan, I tried the same approach but was unable to find any document wether this work with ref.

Comment: This will work with a ref, the ref is just stored as an ObjectId, the `ref` property is for use for `populate`, but doesn't affect the form of this query.

Comment: Post full details with screenshot of DB data and controller. Will check?